# I want To update Date in a table from other table with select but not worked

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to update table **T1** column `T1dt1`.
**T1** Have two column `T1dt1` and `T1dt2`,
`T1DT2` have already dates data

I am copying values from Table **T2** which have only one column `DT`. But when I Tried, it make column null what I write

```
UPDATE T1
  SET T1dt1 = (SELECT DT FROM T2 WHERE DT = T1DT2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-matches are set to `NULL`.  How about filtering them out?

```
UPDATE T1
  SET T1dt1 = (SELECT T2.DT FROM T2 WHERE T2.DT = T1.T1DT2)
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT T2.DT FROM T2 WHERE T2.DT = T1.T1DT2);
```

Note that the query in your question would appear to be more simply written as:

```
UPDATE T1
  SET T1dt1 = T1.T1DT2
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT T2.DT FROM T2 WHERE T2.DT = T1.T1DT2);
```

But I think you just oversimplified the query for the question.

Comment: Thanks for your concern I tried but not worked for me I am making a **dbfiddle** for you that I can easily make you understandable Regards

Comment: Zedan: Creating a fiddle is a good thing, but just using bold test does not make is accessible. To create a like in a comment place the text in brackets then immediately afterward place the url in parentheses. So [dbfiddle](url). However, you should not include additional information in comments, but update the question and place the link there.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a `WHERE` clause is missing; without it, you're updating the whole `t1` table, including rows that don't have a match in `t2` table.

```
update t1 a set
  a.t1dt1 = (select b.dt 
             from t2 b
             where b.dt = a.t1dt2
            )
where exists (select null
              from t2 c
              where c.dt = a.t1dt2
             );
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern I tried but not worked for me I am making a **dbfiddle** for you that I can easily make you understandable Regards

Answer (score 0):

As only matching cases for `t1dt2` and `dt` columns is of your concern, use a *merge* statement containing only
`WHEN MATCHED` option such as

```
MERGE INTO t1 USING (SELECT * FROM t2)
   ON ( t1dt2 = dt )
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t1dt1 = dt
```